# Using Split function to find last folder in file path with only one line

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that looks like

```
Dim arrFold() As String
Dim lastFold As String

arrFold = Split(filePath, "\")
lastFold = arrFold(ubound(arrFold))
```

I am looking for a way to simplify this into just finding the last element on the first line, rather than having to define an array initially, what can be done to avoid adding that to memory?

Answer (score 2):

```
debug.print mid(filePath, instrrev(filePath, chr(92))+1)
debug.print trim(right(replace(filePath, chr(92), space(999)), 999))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub findLast()
Dim myString As String
myString = "\File\lesser\evenless\least"
MsgBox InStrRev(myString, "\")
End Sub
```

Comment: Not one that comes up very often but definitely handy!

Comment: But you are only returning the position; not the last element. You need Mid for that with a nested InstrRev (+1 as well)